# LogicException vs. RuntimeException

Tags: php, exception, php-5.3

I was wondering if there was a rule saying when to use which Exception in PHP... **When do I have to throw a `LogicException` and when a `RuntimeException`?**

For example when it comes to exceptions like `PageNotFoundException`, from which exception class should I inherit?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`LogicException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.logicexception.php) seems like it's for "this can never happen" bug checks:

> Exception that represents error in the program logic. This kind of exception should directly lead to a fix in your code.

A few of the other SPL exceptions, like [`BadFunctionCallException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.badfunctioncallexception.php) inherit from it.

[`RuntimeException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php) is for cases where an error happens that could only be detected while the program is running.  The naming is a holdover from compiled languages, where certain errors can be detected at compile time.  Like `LogicException`, a few of the other SPL exceptions inherit from it.

You probably don't want to use either of these as the base for your own specific extensions unless you know *for sure* that your code could produce another exception in the inheritance hierarchy and you'd want to catch any of those instead of your specific exception or *all* exceptions.

Comment: So in most cases I should rather use `Exception` as the base for my own exceptions?

Comment: Unless you need the intermediate types of Exceptions for some reason, yeah, you should just extend the base class.